# How could I split on comma with out nested loops. don't split inside tags

Tags: python, regex

How could I split on comma with out nested loops?
Don't want to split inside in the tags. the tags are unknown for me.

```
r = ['aa,bb+,cc,[22]tt,df+,ar[/22]', 'cw+,di,ty,<KK>hy+,sb,dd<KK>']

for i in r:
    #print(i)
    lst = []
    for l in re.split(r',\B', i):
        if l.startswith('[') or l.startswith('<'):
            lst.append(l)
        else:
            lst.append(l.split(','))
```

Expected output:

```
aa,bb+,cc,[22]tt,df+,ar[/22]
[['aa', 'bb+', 'cc'], '[22]tt,df+,ar[/22]']
cw+,di,ty,<KK>hy+,sb,dd<KK>
[['cw+', 'di', 'ty'], ['<KK>hy+,sb,dd<KK>']]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: This is unclear, and shows no effort to solve the issue.

Comment: in your example you have always 4 elements so you can use `.split(",", 3)` - `'aa,bb+,cc,[22]tt,df+,ar[/22]'.split(",", 3)` and `'cw+,di,ty,<KK>hy+,sb,dd<KK>'.split(",", 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was with recursion:

```
pattern = re.compile('|'.join((
    r'(?P<PROCENT>(<%|\[)(?P<PROC>[0-9]{1,2})(\:|\])(?P<DATA>.+?)(>|\[/(?P=PROC)\]))', 
    r'(?P<SEP>\s*[;,]\s*)',
    r'(?P<VALUE>[a-zA-Z0-9]+\+?)'
)))

def range_parse(text: str, proc: float = 1.0):
    for m in pattern.finditer(text):
        lastgroup = m.lastgroup
        if lastgroup == 'SEP':
            continue
        elif lastgroup == 'PROCENT':
            yield from range_parse(m.group('DATA'), float(m.group('PROC')) / 100)
        elif ':' in m.group():
            data, proc = m.group().split(':')
            proc = float(proc)
        else:
            data = m.group()
        yield (lastgroup, data, proc)
```